# Run javascript block just once

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript function and I want to alert 12, 24, 36 ... and so on in the multiples of 12 . I have attached the code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        var global1=12;
        var final;
        var check;
        if(check) {
            final=global1;
            check=true;
        } else {
            final=final+12;
        }
        alert(final);
    }

    test();
    test();
    test();
</script>
```

Comment: You need to declare `global1` outside of your function.

Comment: You code does not make much sense; you only set `check` when it is `true` (never...) and all your variables are local: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: Apart from that you have failed to tell us what the problem is and what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: If(check)... Never saticefy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a closure over the value and the final value and return a function for updating the value until it reaches the final value.

```js
var test = function (final) {
        var value = 0;
        return function () {
            if (value < final) {
                value += 12;
            }
            console.log(value);
        };
    }(36); // call with final value

test();
test();
test();
test();
```

Comment: Looking at the OP's original code, this might be a bit too much :-)

Comment: @jeroen, it is just another approach without using global to tackle that problem. this answer is just an offer, if op like to have some more tools.

Comment: To be clear, I was referring to the OP's programming skills, not your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment, here is a much simpler version for your function :

```js
var count = 0;

function twelve(){
  count += 12;
  console.log(count);
}

twelve();
twelve();
twelve();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variables globally instead of function block.
Example:

```js
var global1 = 12;
var final;
var check = true;

function test()
{
    if(check) {
        final = global1;
        check = false;
    } else {
        final = final + 12;
    }
    alert(final);
}

test();
test();
test();
```